# In Postgresql how to get base64 decoded values as string instead of hex representation?

Tags: postgresql, base64

In Python I encoded one string,

```
>>> base64.b64encode('1111')
'MTExMQ=='
```

Now when I try to decode it in Postgresql I got Hex values instead of the original string.

```
=# select decode('MTExMQ==', 'base64');

   decode   
------------
 \x31313131
```

How can I get the original string without any change in Postgresql?

Comment: if you `set bytea_output to 'escape';` (default on earlier versions)  it will return wanted result

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `convert_from` to turn binary data into a varchar:

```
select convert_from(decode('MTExMQ==', 'base64'), 'UTF8')
```

But note that this can be lossy (or fail) if the input is really binary data (and not some text), such as an image file.

There should be no need to store Base64-encoded data in Postgresql. You can use one of the binary column types and store the data directly (and more compactly).

Answer (score 13):

`decode()` returns a byte array (`bytea`) not a "hex string".

The format you see is the [default textual representation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT) of a `bytea` which is e.g. used by `psql` when displaying `bytea` values. Other SQL clients might display that differently.

To convert a byte array to a readable string, you need to use `encode()`

```
select encode('\x31313131', 'base64');
```

If you change `bytea_output` to `escape` and then cast the result to `text` you can achieve the same thing:

```
set bytea_output to 'escape';
select decode('MTExMQ==', 'base64')::text;
```

If you are using `psql` you don't need the cast.

Answer (score 0):

Decoding

```
SELECT CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(field, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8') FROM table;
```

Encoding

```
SELECT ENCODE(CONVERT_TO(field, 'UTF-8'), 'base64') FROM table;
```

Answer (score -1):

I always use my own method

```
create function owndecode(password character varying) returns bytea
    language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  _length int;
begin
  _length := char_length(password);

  if (_length in(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)) then
    return decode(password || '=', 'base64');

  elseif (_length in (6, 10, 14)) then
    return decode(password || '==', 'base64');

  elseif (_length in(8, 12)) then
    return decode(password, 'base64');

  else
    return char_length(password)::varchar;

  end if;
end;
$$;
```